# Module is not listed in IntelliJ "Run Configuration"

Tags: intellij-idea

**Setup:**
I have imported the [Git project](https://github.com/FlowForwarding/enetconf) into IntelliJ.
I compiled the project using "make compile"

**Issue:**
I tried to create a "Run Configuration". The Module is not listed in the drop-down window.

**Debugging:**
I compared it with a working setup wherein a project was created using "File->New Project" and wherein .iml was automatically created. I see that the problematic project does not have a .iml file. I could not make out any other differences.

Is the absence of .iml file the root-cause for the issue? If so, how to generate this .iml file? Rather than manual writing, I prefer to generate it using GUI to avoid any manual errors. Please suggest.

In Eclipse IDE, one can convert a project from one type to another. Ex: normal project to Maven project. A default project to Java project by editing .project file.

[image]

Comment: Seems project wasn't imported correctly. Please try to reopen it or reimport.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried both reopen & reimport. Sorry to say that it did not work

Comment: Please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after importing for error records.